# Rails polymorphic association: Struggling with form to input tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

I have a model with movies and actors and I want both to be taggeable. I know there's a gem for that but I thought I'd teach myself polymorphic associations :)
Basic functionality works (I can do stuff like amovie.tags.create etc...) but now I want forms for movies and actors where tags can be selected and deselected.

Problem : I cannot deselect a tag:
While selecting a tag (that exists) works, when I deselect a tag, I get an error. Here's the relevant code:
Movie Form:

```
<%= form.collection_select(:tag_ids, Tag.order(:name), :id, :name, {}, { class: 'selectize-tag', multiple: true }) %>
```

movies controller - update section as well as movies_params private function:

```
  def update    
    respond_to do |format|
      if @movie.update(movie_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @movie, notice: "Movie was successfully updated." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @movie }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @movie.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def movie_params
    params.require(:movie).permit(:title, :runtime, :country, :release_year, :sort_title, tag_ids: [])
  end
```

Error I get:

```
Mysql2::Error: Column 'taggeable_id' cannot be null
```

Params - I think the problem is the line that has tag IDs and one of them is ""

```
{"_method"=>"patch",
 "authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "movie"=>
  {"title"=>"The Avengers",
   "sort_title"=>"Avengers",
   "release_year"=>"2012",
   "country"=>"US",
   "runtime"=>"143",
   "tag_ids"=>["", "3"]},
 "commit"=>"Update Movie",
 "id"=>"48"}
```

So not sure what I need to do for that empty tag id there to not be submitted but rather to trigger "remove tag with ID xyz from movie abc?

Comment: When asking - just focus on one question. Questions with a lack of focus are very difficult to answer and are often closed/downvoted. Here your first task really should be investigating why you're getting a blank id - do you actually have a bad value in your DB? Move `Tag.order(:name)` into the controller (querying in the view is questionable) and set a breakpoint.

Comment: are you using taggable gem?

Comment: Thanks max - I have split this into two questions (removed the "selectize / javascript" part and moved it somewhere else). I am not sure what you mean... move "Tag.order... into controller"? Felix - I know there is a taggable gem but as said I wanted to try myself to learn polymorphic associations :)